# is it possible to install two CTI Adapter (Five9 and Avaya) in a single Salesforce Org?

Tags: apex, cti, softphone

I have a single service Cloud salesforce Org and wants to be used globally, Few geographical region uses Five9 standard Adaper already installed in a salesforce Org and some use Avaya for CTI but not on salesforce platform, i want to use single salesforce org. is it possible to install Two CTI standard Adapter in a single salesforce Org?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to install two CTI adapter in single org. Once you install 2 cti in salesforce then you have to create two call center by navigating to Quick search and then search call center.

Create the call center by importing the xml file provided by CTI package.

After creating call centers then go to call center and assign different call center user.

Hope it helps!!!
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] this post so that it provides a complete answer, here. Please use links to support your answer, rather than to provide content. See [answer].

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details

Comment: @Manish Porwal, If a User assigned with both the Call Center, will there be any conflict during Call?
Could you please share any challenges if we implement two CTI in a single Org.

Comment: First thing it is not possible to assign a single user to multiple call center. Because if you go to user record detail call center is a look up field on the user record. So there is no chance for conflict